# How to get the objects of an object using foreach in Laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get all the order details that are linked to and order which is linked to a booking.

Let's say I pass the booking id and wanna retrieve all the order details linked to it. but the orderOrderDetials in the view returns an empty array even if there is record in the database.

Booking Model

```
protected $fillable = [
    'room_id',
    'invoice_id',
    'order_id',
    'status',
    'start_time',
    'end_time',
];
public function invoice()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Invoice::class, 'invoice_id');
}

public function order()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Order::class, 'order_id');
}
```

Order Model

```
protected $fillable = [
    'booking_id',
    'serial_number',
    'subtotal',
];
public function orderOrderDetails()
{
    return $this->hasMany(OrderDetail::class, 'order_id', 'id');
}
public function booking()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Booking::class, 'booking_id');
}
```

Order Details Model

```
protected $fillable = [
    'order_id',
    'order_item_id',
    'quantity',
    'amount',
];

public function order()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Order::class, 'order_id');
}

public function order_item()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'order_item_id');
}
```

Home Controller

```
 class HomeController
 {
   public function index()
   {
     $bookings = Booking::where('status', "in_progress")->orWhere('status', "unpaid")->get();   \\ shows 5 objects when dd($bookings)
    return view('home', compact('bookings'));
   }
 }
```

Home View

```
 @if ($bookings !== NULL)
   @foreach ($bookings as  $booking)
     @foreach ($booking->order->orderOrderDetails as  $orderDetail)   \\$booking->order->orderOrderDetails returns an empty array even tho there are records in the database
       <p>{{ $orderDetail->item->name ?? ''}}</p>
       <p>{{ $orderDetail->item->price ?? ''}}</p>
       <p>{{ $orderDetail->item->quantity ?? ''}}</p>
     @endforeach
   @endforeach
 @endif
```

Order Details Table

[image: Order Details Table]

Orders Table

[image: Orders Table]

Bookings Table

[image: Bookings Table]

Comment: maybe, im wrong, but that's not a problem with 'id' column which not exists in your models, try return $this->hasMany(OrderDetail::class, 'order_id', 'order_item_id');

Comment: So what's the actual issue here? You say *"I am trying to"*, but you don't actually specify a problem... Is something going wrong with your code? Are you getting any kind of errors? What are you expecting to happen vs what is _actually_ happening? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74733149/edit) and include more details.

Comment: doesn't $id in this line refer to the id of the object created from this model>? I am liking it as "this model "Order" has many "Order Details" and the "order_id" in the "Order Details" model refers to the "id" in the current model which is "order"

Comment: @TimLewis sorry I commented the issue in the code itseld, the orderOrderDetials in the view returns an empty array.

Comment: Ah gotcha, it flows off my screen a bit, but I see it now. So yeah, it's likely an issue with how you have the relationships defined then; checking that now. Sidenote, `orderOrderDetails` is a silly name; `order` is the name of the Model you're in, you don't need to include that as a prefix; `public function orderDetails` is better, as you'd then call it as `$order->orderDetails` instead of `$order->orderOrderDetails` 

Comment: @TimLewis okay will change it to be more simple, thanks  :)

Comment: So the `order_details` looks like it's a pivot table between `Order` and `OrderItem`, so you could actually define it in `Order.php` as `public function orderItem() { return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'order_details', 'order_id', 'order_item_id')->withPivot('quantity'); }`, then you can do `@foreach($booking->order->orderItems as $orderItem)` then `{{ $orderItem->name }}`. Full documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many. Typically, you don't define a Model for a Pivot Table. You can, though, and the documentation shows that too 

Comment: @TimLewis That worked for me. I used the same logic u commented and modified it to my code and it worked. Thanks.